# How do I find if there is a significant difference in the number of males and females in a single population?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

Also, how do I find if there is a significant difference in the number of males in two populations? In SPSS please!

Comment: What options do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to know whether a difference in the number of males and females is significantly different or not?

Comment: Yes, I understood your goal. But what strategies can you come up with? Have you done any research?

Comment: Mr Cat, I am really unsure what you are trying to say. Well, if you are talking about my study, it is about exploring the rectal cancer cases in our hospital!

Comment: What is the hypothesized percent of male?

Comment: Please take the time to write a sufficiently detailed question to get a proper answer.

Comment: There were 984 males (54%) and 837 females (46%) in the database. I wanted to know if this difference is significant.

Comment: Unless the database consists of a random sample of a population, any calculation of "significance" could be misleading. How were these data collected and what would be the consequences of determining there is a "significant" difference between the male and female proportions?

Comment: This is from a national database in USA. The test is done to determine if more number of males have rectal cancer versus females in a particular age group.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SPSS to do that, refer to [this page](http://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/07d2pop.html) and [this page](http://voices.yahoo.com/statistics-difference-between-two-population-proportions-7301090.html) for the formulas. You can easily do that with a calculator, which, well, includes the Compute function in SPSS.

Comment: Isn't the question merely whether the proportions of males are *different,* not that they equal some hypothetical proportion?

Comment: @whuber Yes, I just got too excited. Revised.

Comment: Thanks for the revision, but it still seems off the mark.  You are now proposing to test the hypothesis that one population has 50% males rather than that two populations have the *same* proportions of males.

Comment: @whuber Oh... right. LOL, sorry it's been a long day. Will revise.

Answer (score 1):

I think any introductory statistic textbook will have a similar if not identical example.  You probably want to look under "Test for proportions" and carry out the calculations by hand. This could be easier than explaining what to do in the drop down menu of a program.